# number guessing game java

Tags: java, random

I'm writing a java code that asks the user to guess the computer's random number, which I have fine, however, what I would like to do is have a message that corresponds to the number of guesses it took the user.

For example if the user guessed the random number in 1 try there would be in output of "Excellent!" if the user guessed the answer in 2-4 tries "Good Job" and so on..

I guess I haven't tried anything, because I'm not sure where to stick the code?
I know it would have to be if guess == 1 then do this else if code >1<=3 then do this and so on.. but where in my code? should it be in the while loop with the nested if's as well?

Here is my updated code, it runs and compiles the exact way I needed to create it.  Thanks for all of the help!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int compNum = rand.nextInt(100);
        int count = 0;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int userGuess;  
        boolean win = false;        
        while (win == false ){
            System.out.print("Enter a guess between 1 and 100: ");
            userGuess = keyboard.nextInt();
            count++;
            if(userGuess < 1 || userGuess > 100){
                System.out.println("Your guess is out of range.  Pick a number between 1 and 100.");
                System.out.println();
            }
            else if (userGuess == compNum){
                win = true;
                System.out.println("Congratulations!  Your answer was correct! ");
            }       
            else if (userGuess < compNum){
                System.out.println("Your guess was too low.  Try again. ");
                System.out.println();
            }
            else if (userGuess > compNum){
                System.out.println("Your guess was too high.  Try again. ");
                System.out.println();
            }

        }
        if(count == 1){
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("I had chosen " + compNum + " as the target number.");
            System.out.println("You guessed it in " + count + " tries.");
            System.out.println("That was lucky!");
        }
        else if (count > 1 && count <= 4){
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("I had chosen " + compNum + " as the target number.");
            System.out.println("You guessed it in " + count + " tries.");
            System.out.println("That was amazing!");
        }
        else if (count > 4 && count <= 6){
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("I had chosen " + compNum + " as the target number.");
            System.out.println("You guessed it in " + count + " tries.");
            System.out.println("That was good.");
        }
        else if (count > 6 && count <= 7){
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("I had chosen " + compNum + " as the target number.");
            System.out.println("You guessed it in " + count + " tries.");
            System.out.println("That was OK.");
        }               
        else if (count > 7 && count <= 9){
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("I had chosen " + compNum + " as the target number.");
            System.out.println("You guessed it in " + count + " tries.");
            System.out.println("That was not very good.");
        }
        else if (count > 10){
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("I had chosen " + compNum + " as the target number.");
            System.out.println("You guessed it in " + count + " tries.");
            System.out.println("This just isn't your game.");

        }
    }
        }
```

Comment: What you need to do is show us the code that is problematic and explain what you've tried.  Your question is in danger of being closed because you haven't provided any relevant details besides your objective.  Start by deciding how to map number of guesses to a "reward" phrase and then write code to implement that mapping.

Comment: Create a function that takes the number of tries it took as a parameter and return a string with the message you wanted. You'll need to use some sort of control structure to do this, the simplest probably just being a bunch of if-else statements. As for this question here it's off topic because it's hard to actually give you a concise answer, including some code where you attempted to solve the problem would have been good.

Comment: I'm sorry, like I said very new here, saw a few posts about the code but it didn't correlate to my question. What I need help with I guess is how to fit that into my code, should it all be in one big nested loop? I'm sorry I'm trying to find out how to add my code to show what I have..

Answer (score 2):

You could count the iterations. Something like.

```
boolean notCorrect = true;
int guesses = 0;
while(notCorrect){
    //Code for checking user input. 
    //break out if true
    guesses++;
}
```

Sorry did that backwards.

elsewhere

```
if(guesses < 2) {
    // display message
}
// include other if's to determine which message to display.
```

You could put the if statement that decides which message to display in the if that checks whether the guess is correct. But pull that out of the loop. That way your only running that code if the user actually guessed correctly.

```
if (userGuess == compNum){
    win = true;
    System.out.println("Congratulations! Your answer was correct! ");
    // put message decision here...
}
```

Comment: thank you @Mikejg101 . I know I have to do something like this here but the thing I'm unsure of is where to put the code at.. would it still be in my while loop or nested with my other nested if's?

Comment: No problem. I'm happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a count in an `int i;` and every time the user guesses **wrong** (not if the user gets the answer right, do `i++`. Then, have something like the following where you respond ti the correct answer:

```
if(i == 0) System.out.println("Perfect!");    //Got it the first time
else if(i == 1) System.out.println("Nice!");  //Got it on the second try
else if(i <= 4) System.out.println("Good Job!");   //Got it between the second and fifth time
else if(i <= 8) System.out.println("Okay!");   //Got it between 6th and 9th time
else System.out.println("Hmmm... Try to do better next time!");  //took more than 10 times to get it right
```